# Dynamically generate array elements from yaml file in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, yaml

Given the following yaml file stored in **my_yaml** that contains varying sets of dictionary keys and/or class variables (denoted by self._*):

```
config1.json:
- [[foo, bar], [hello, world]]
config2.json:
- [[foo], [self._hi]]
```

From the json file, I want to populate a new list of tuples.  The items in each tuple are determined by looking up dict keys in this yaml file.

So if I iterate through a dictionary called **config1.json**, and I have an empty list called **config_list**, I want to do something like:

```
config_list.append(tuple[i['foo']['bar],i['hello']['world']])
```

But if it were **config2.json**, I want to do something like:

```
config_list.append(tuple[i['foo'],self._hi])
```

I can do this in a less dynamic way:

```
for i in my_yaml['config1.json'][0]:
    config_list.append(tuple([ i[my_yaml[asset][0][0]][my_yaml[asset][0][1]],i[my_yaml[asset][1][0]][my_yaml[asset][1][1]]]))
```

or:

```
for i in my_yaml['config2.json'][0]:
    config_list.append(tuple([ i[my_yaml[asset][0][0]],i[my_yaml[asset][1][0]]]))
```

Instead I would like to dynamically generate the contents of **config_list**

Any ideas or alternatives would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: First, what is that `tuple[[i['foo']['bar],i['hello']['world']]` supposed to be? Do you want the tuple `(i['foo'['bar'], i['hello']['world'])`, or something different?

Comment: But meanwhile: I don't know why these things are called `config1.json` and `config2.json` when they're not JSON strings but YAML arrays. But it looks like most of what you want to do is treat each sub-array as a "key path" into `i` of arbitrary length, instead of a fixed length of 2 in `config1.json` and 1 in `config2.json`? If so, that's pretty easy… but I'm not sure how you expect that `[self._hi]` to be turned into `self._hi` instead of `i['self._hi']`. What's the rule that makes that happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are bit confusing things, first of all because you are referring
to a file in "From the json [*sic*] file" and there is no JSON file mentioned
anywhere in the question. There are **mapping** keys that look like
filenames for JSON files, so I hope we can assume you mean "From the value
associated with the mapping key that ends in the string `.json`".

The other confusing thing is that you obfuscate the fact that you want tuples
but load list nested in list nested in lists from you YAML document. 
If you want tuples, it is much more clear to specify them in your YAML document:

```
config1.json:
- !!python/tuple [[foo, bar], [hello, world]]
config2.json:
- !!python/tuple [[foo], [self._hi]]
```

So you can do:

```
import sys
import ruamel.yaml


yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML(typ='unsafe')
with open('my.yaml') as fp:
    my_yaml = yaml.load(fp)

for key in my_yaml:
    for idx, elem in enumerate(my_yaml[key]):
        print('{}[{}] -> {}'.format(key, idx, my_yaml[key][idx]))
```

which directly gives you the tuples you seem to want instead of lists you need to process:

```
config1.json[0] -> (['foo', 'bar'], ['hello', 'world'])
config2.json[0] -> (['foo'], ['self._hi'])
```

In your question you hard code access to the first and only
element of the sequence that are the values for the root level
mapping. This forces you to use the final `[0]` in your for loop. I
assume you are going to have multiple elements in those sequences, but
for a good question you should leave that out, as it is irrelevant for the
question on how to get the tuples, and thereby only obfuscating things.

Please note that you need to keep control over your input, as using
`typ='unsafe'` is, you guessed, unsafe. If you cannot guarantee that
use `typ='safe'` and register and use the tag `!tuple`.